# XAML Universal App: How to make a horizontal scrolling ListView

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I am having trouble getting a Horizontally scrolling ListView to work.  I get very close, but then something just doesn't quite work right.

Here is my current XAML I have come up with so far after searching the Internet.  The items are shown Horizontally, but the problem with it is that it still just wants to scroll vertically even though I'm trying to force everything for Horizontal on and Vertical off.

Does anyone have any insight on what I am doing wrong?

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollWatchlist" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,3" DataContext="{Binding MovieViewModel}"
              HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"

              VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              IsVerticalRailEnabled="False"

              IsScrollInertiaEnabled="True">
    <ScrollViewer.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ListView Margin="0,5,0,3" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding DataContext}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListViewItem Margin="0,0,5,0" Tag="{Binding ID}">
                            <Image Source="{Binding FormattedPosterUri}" Width="92" />
                        </ListViewItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer.Template>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**UPDATE: Here is a working XAML example for anyone who comes across this question:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvwMovieWatchlist" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,3" ItemsSource="{Binding MovieViewModel}"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">

    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListViewItem Margin="0,0,5,0" Tag="{Binding ID}">
                <Image Source="{Binding FormattedPosterUri}" Width="92" />
            </ListViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need the `ScrollViewer`, and also you should get those properties in the `ListView`

```
<ListView  Margin="0,5,0,3" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True">
```

Comment: Thank you.  Didn't realize the ScrollViewer properties are accessible.  Though, it makes sense now.

Comment: You also need to disable VerticalScrolling, otherwise mousewheel button won't work.

Comment: Yeah, I disabled that as well (though this is a WP 8 app,so I don't have to worry about the mouse wheel at the moment).  But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I recently needed the same and blogged about it: http://depblog.weblogs.us/2015/03/25/show-items-scrolling-horizontally-with-listview-in-winrt/ maybe you can get some extra pointers there ;)

Answer (score 5):

It is recommended to use GridView for displaying items with horizontal scrolling. Just replace ListView with Gridview in your code.

However, you can use ListView with horizontal scrollbar:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
```

Comment: Can you post a link where Microsoft or the general populace says it is "recommended"?  Also, using a Grid doesn't give the tap animation feedback for selecting a specific item like ListView does.  I am specifically wanting that functionality.

Comment: This is one of the questions in microsoft certification exam 70-484 basics of developing windows store apps. Its is mentioned also here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780650.aspx, but not as recommendation, but default behaviour. Regarding the animation, i'm not sure what you mean? I'm getting exactly the same feedback, but i'm on windows 8...

Comment: The important difference between GridView and ListView is gesture for selecting items (in case you have click enabled). ListView's selection gesture is swipe Left->Right, but if you have horizontal scrollviewer, according to design guidelines you should use swipe Up->Down and that's what GridView does.

Comment: Well, maybe GridView would give that behavior.  I have never used that before (I'm totally new to WP8 apps, this is my first one).  Didn't even dawn on me when you said GridView above; totally overlooked that I was just thinking Grid since I've only ever used Grid so far and ListView.  I'll have to look into GridView more.  It actually may contain some behavior I'm interested in for something else I'm working on.  Thanks :)

Comment: I totally recommend you to read book called exam ref - certification name -  preparation guide, e.g. https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/exam-ref-70-484-essentials-of-developing-windows-store-9780735676848. They are great for learning the official microsoft recommendations with lots of samples and explanations. You can also have a look at what the exam covers: https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-484.aspx and find MSDN links to each topic. You may find list of msdn link on blogs of people that went trought the certification